# How to put if condition for empty material index

Tags: python, node-editor

I need to have access to the active material and its nodes (if they exist), so I wrote this script that has a problem, when the object has no materials, when the object does not exist, and of course if the object is 'MESH' type

```
import bpy 

ob = bpy.context.active_object
index = ob.active_material_index     
mat = ob.material_slots[index].material
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
my_node = nodes.get("My node name")

if my_node:
    print("My node is inside!")
else:
    print("My node not inside!")
```

work only if object is not none, object is 'MESH' type and If inside have slot material.
else rightly give me that error:

```
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 0 out of range, size 0
```

I can't figure out how to assign variables in an if statement, because I know that in python you can't (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more info on if statements in Python [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp).

You can find a lot of useful information about bpy in Blender's Python console using the auto complete function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>):

[image]

The script you are after could be something like this:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
name = "My_node_name"
if obj is not None:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        if obj.active_material is not None:
            if obj.active_material.use_nodes:
                nodes = obj.active_material.node_tree.nodes
                if nodes.get(name) is not None:
                    print(name + " node is in the material's node tree.")
                else:
                    print(name + " node is not in the material's node tree.")
            else:
                print("Material does not ue nodes.")
        else:
            print("Object does not have an active material.")    
    else:
        print("Object is not a mesh.")
else:
    print("There is no active object currently in the scene.")
```

Comment: Ty for my script it worked well